# How can I get the BoundField from a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdImoveis" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsGrid">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome" DataField="NomeCompleto" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnAlterar" ImageUrl="../tema/_Internas/icons/edit.png" runat="server" OnClick="btnChange_Click" /> 
                    </Columns>
</GridView>
```

How can i get the value of this field in code behind and pass the value to my btnChange_Click event ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your asking what I think, you'd like want to handle the OnRowCommand of your GridView and capture the button action in there.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdImoveis" onrowcommand="grdImoveis_RowCommand" ...
```

Code-Behind:

```
 protected void grdImoveis_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "BUTTON")
        {
            // Check value of e.CommandArgument and do something here:
        }
    }
```

And change your imagebutton to something like so by setting `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` to the value you want to pass. You also have to wrap it in a TemplateField:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton CommandName="BUTTON" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("NomeCompleto") %>' ID="ibtnAlterar" ImageUrl="../tema/_Internas/icons/edit.png" runat="server"  />
</ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I have an ImageButton...when you click there, you can modify the data of the specific client. How can I get the specific client if the name of this client is in my BoundField in GridView

Comment: @Lucas_Santos Edited the answer to wrap the imagebutton in a templatefield, forgot that part. But the <%#Eval("...")%> is setting that data in the commandargument. You'r not going to be able to do a normal button click handler I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use CommandArgument property like this

```
CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex  %>'
```

inside a `TemplateField` and then in your code behind 'OnRowCommand' event handler use it like this:

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    object dataItem = gv.Rows[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].DataItem;
}
```